# NGINX HTTPS Server barfing on .crt and .key files

Tags: ssl, nginx, pem, pki

**Question:**

Is there anything special about the way nginx wants its .pem/.crt and .key files formated?  I can't get nginx running... it always craps out complaining about the cert/key file.

**Ask:**

Anyone want to share with me a (sanitized) copy of their .pem/crt and .key file on a (non-production) system that is working fine?  Or otherwise tell me what I am doing wrong (see below)

**Errors:**

After configuring nginx.conf to point to  ssltest.cuddletech.com.**crt** and depositing the .crt (and key) file in /nginx/servers... and then run `nginx` to start the server, I get the following error:

```
nginx: [emerg] unexpected end of file, expecting ";" or "}" in /usr/local/etc/nginx/servers/ssltest.cuddletech.com.crt:63
```

**Troubleshooting:**
`

If I go in and put a `;`at the end of the file (right after the second 
`-----END CERTIFICATE-----;` (it's a bundle containing both the leaf and the intermediate ca).  Now,it no longer complains about the unexpected end, but rather complains:

```
 nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "-----BEGIN" in /usr/local/etc/nginx/servers/ssltest.cuddletech.com.crt:62
```

If I then go in and delete the -----BEGIN part, it continues to complain about the unknown directive... this time starting with the first few characters of the encoded cert.

Interestingly, If I change the file type to `.pem` (keeping the ; at the end,  and update nginx.conf to look for the .pem).   Now, it does not complain at all about the certificate file, but rather starts complaining the same way about the **KEY** file:

```
$ nginx: [emerg] unexpected end of file, expecting ";" or "}" in /usr/local/etc/nginx/servers/ssltest.cuddletech.com.key:28
```

Putting the `;` or `}` at the end of the .key file makes nginx complain:

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "-----BEGIN" in /usr/local/etc/nginx/servers/ssltest.cuddletech.com.key:27
```

Also interesting is that both time it complains about the `-----BEGIN` it indicates a line number at the end of the file, not at the beginning.

**How I Generated The Cert and Key files:**

I generated the cert using Hashicorp's Vault PKI backend  ([per this howto](http://cuddletech.com/?p=959) )

I cut and pasted the leaf and intermediate cert into one file and the private key into another file.

They look like this:

Certificate bundle:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIE/DCCAuSgAwIBAgIUIKX6kkLIidtRvnx0nafFH9SunaIwDQYJKoZIhvc
NAQELBQAwKTEnMCGA1UEAxMeQ3VkZGxldGVjaCBPcHMgSW50ZXJtZWRpYXRlIENBMB4X
DTE3MDkwOTAwMTgxNVoXDTE3MTAwOTAwMTg0NVowITEfMB0GA1UEAxMWc3NsdGVz
.... 
NW9I2ThBDp0uo7LcIO7hmHhNun6apGSlgf6Gj1L63dp
Fe+hoQpCNOGfoc2P+4uJZenqiax5dFqskiBVkQ7uyVFxf5ydF5pjzwF/QFFcKKok
SkRjCJmrVxD/7V6H8u+hSRJuXGXNIIuhhUmYhWoNZpnZEUyDPOuMWHjxq7ZfPHlO
A039BhLFI0msEBfk+DunhYA+xyBIhK0Lq3pqcc7zH9A=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFpTCCA42gAwIBAgIUbXR6po8/oWmxgTVYuhxHDAM1prUwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL
BQAwHTEbMBkGA1UEAxMSQ3VkZGxldGVjaCBSb290IENBMB4XDTE3MDkwODIyNTI0
OFoXDTE4MDkwODIyNTMxOFowKTEnMCUGA1UEAxMeQ3VkZGxldGVjaCBPcHMgSW50
.....
ZXJtZWRpYXRlIENBMIICIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8AMIICCgKCAgEAwuTe
h9gpV4RcibYNOptsDJHomUZaEkRs3ppGt1asnM5os7L17ExFS8PLSY0SbhB75Vo1
TLlgH2MkDGHbw5bcgY0fYXvKqk1y6JjLFBnmiGHe8mHt9XaWkbnwP/E7CttGr2GC
SaT7RxDN2pHXceTnmLOiz0Dk1ZpssldMVD1MQeSQspuBp9s2sWfXtkrLluPLOZH0
C1WXl+H/7giQggXPmMVLhnxPaaAwU0DNX0IZjzE1fqazBbrx36n7baVdUgRczkD2
Xiht8pnAdbUFdp8byeupDkPJ2vLyMLocvSO6z1m4+drXlgFPBLSgKXGvnw5A8b+S
dqKRe55MBNxpws0E4OjMVwVXlMctcLCogmx6jFYjWSJUQgKLHCi2JVWW6ajlKOfV
Gn/opA11kWKb
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

The Private Key file:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAyWnbF5T5vIlrcVHG82S+u/GESnlhAiX6maUYmpQMVOGsmjWr
XOKFGQbFW796FgENrt1PzXlYT8/aKyT215KomxkC4bWV0daobC5p+fzusVyV51Si
.....
smzFwxewOYa4FU3KGgRlscBooaRumwpXid3IPwfsBzOCdNQ8zXyaqSZeStewxUBq
ZtMEDpD3q7noZQU85cQs4SlbOOscXEUMUaeKQDhC2FWW9qlM5NKU
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

The HTTPS server section of nginx.conf

```
# HTTPS server
#
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  ssltest.cuddletech.com;

    ssl_certificate      /usr/local/etc/nginx/servers/ssltest.cuddletech.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /usr/local/etc/nginx/servers/ssltest.cuddletech.com.key;

#    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
#    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    location / {
        root  /user/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
include servers/*;
}
```

**My Set-up:**

Mac OS X 10.12.6
nginx version: nginx/1.12.1
  built by clang 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
  built with OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017
  TLS SNI support enabled

**TIA for any advice!!!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem us the `include servers/*;` statement. You are including everything in the servers directory as config. So the certificates also are being loaded as config

Either change it to

```
include servers/*.conf;
```

Or remove it if there are no configs you are including

Comment: Humm.... that did not work out for me.

When I commented out the include /server I got:
    nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (13: Permission denied)

Comment: Humm.... that did not work out for me.

When I commented out the include /server I got:

     nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (13: Permission denied)

When did the Server/*.conf thing I got:

    nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (13: Permission denied)

When I did:

cp   /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf  /usr/local/etc/nginx/servers/nginx.conf

I got:

    nginx: [emerg] "worker_processes" directive is not allowed here in /usr/local/etc/nginx/servers/nginx.conf:3

Comment: You need to use sudo and don't copy nginx.conf to servers folder

Comment: Awesome.   Thanks!  Now  I can go to sleep :)